# how to remove square brackets and quotation mark when convert array to list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBYIs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdpPq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odQ16.png)

As you can see in the picture, I want to convert the array to a list and finally to excel. But the problem I have is all the data on both sides have square brackets and quotations. what should I do to remove them?
please help me to solve this problem, thank you!

To put it simply: My list is like [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]  and I want to convert it to a,b,c

here is my code

```
def top_rank(result, md_adj, miRNAs, diseases):
row, col = result.shape
rows_list = []

for i in range(3):
    pidx = np.argsort(-result[:, i])
    sidx = np.argwhere(md_adj[:, i] == 1)
    indices = np.argwhere(np.isin(pidx, sidx))
    index = np.delete(pidx, indices)
    a = diseases[i]
    b = miRNAs[index]
    c = np.vstack([a,b]).tolist()
    rows_list.append(c)


df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
df = df.T
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: You can use `print(", ".join(your_list))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it doesn't work. My list is like [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]  and I want to convert it to a,b,c. And I want to save it to the list rather than print it.

Comment: So your list is strings that every string have the brackets?

Comment: Instead of providing screenshots of your code, can you please include it in your question as text? You can use  single quotes ("`") to mark the start and end of inline code and triple quotes ("```") to mark the start and end of code blocks. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for details on formatting.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to save your data in a csv-file, which you can then load into Excel.

Comment: @Bernana yes, every string has brackets and quotation marks. The data in NumPy is String form, when it converts to list it has brackets and quotation marks.

Comment: @wikikikitiki  Ok, I included my code already. And I have to use the function df = df.T, so  maybe I can't use the csv

Comment: Thanks, can you add a small dataset as well? Also, if you're using pandas you shouldn't need the csv module, I stand corrected.

Comment: you have nested lists `[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]` so you should use nested for-loop to flatten to `['a', 'b', 'c']` - ie. `flatten = [item[0] for item in your_list]` - and later you can use `print(", ".join(flatten))``

Comment: you could also use fact that `["a"] + ["b"]` gives `["a", "b"]` - so you can use `sum()` with `[]` as starting value - `flatten = sum(your_list, [])`

Comment: and if you have `numpy.array` then you should use `arr.reshape((arr.shape[0],))` or `arr.flatten()`

Comment: @wikikikitiki Thank you for your warm-hearted. And furas's answer has helped me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have nested lists `[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]` then you can use `for`-loop to make it flatten `['a', 'b', 'c']`

```
data = [ ['a'], ['b'], ['c']]

flatten = [row[0] for row in data]

print(flatten)
```

Or you can also use fact that `["a"] + ["b"]` gives `["a", "b"]` - so you can use `sum()` with `[]` as starting value

```
data = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]

flatten = sum(data, [])

print(flatten)
```

And if you have `numpy.array` then you could simply use `arr.flatten()`

```
import numpy as np

data = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
arr = np.array(data)

flatten = arr.flatten()

print(flatten)
```

**BUT** ... images show that you have `[['X', 'Y'], ['a'], ['b'], ['c']]` and first element has two values - and this need different method to create flatten `['X Y', 'a', 'b', 'c']`. It needs to use `for`-loop with `join()`

```
data = [['X', 'Y'], ['a'], ['b'], ['c']]

flatten = [' '.join(row) for row in data]

print(flatten)
```

The same using `map()`

```
data = [['X', 'Y'], ['a'], ['b'], ['c']]

flatten = list(map(",".join, data))

print(flatten)
```

---

And when you have flatten list then your code+

```
rows_list = [flatten]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
df = df.T

print(df)
```

gives

```
     0
0  X Y
1    a
2    b
3    c
```

without `[]` and `''`

---

**BTW:**

If you would creat dictionary `rows_list[a] = b` (after converting `a` to string and `b` to flatten list) then you wouldn't need to transpose `df = df.T`

```
import pandas as pd

a = [['X', 'Y']]
b = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]

print('a:', a)
print('b:', b)
print('---')

a = " ".join(sum(a, []))
b = sum(b, [])

print('a:', a)
print('b:', b)
print('---')

rows = dict()
rows[a] = b

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(df)
```

gives

```
a: [['X', 'Y']]
b: [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
---
a: X Y
b: ['a', 'b', 'c']
---
  X Y
0   a
1   b
2   c
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! It helps me to solve my problem and the given example is very easy to understand. Unfortunately, I can't upvote your answer as I'm new to Stackoverflow

Comment: as I rember you may have to wait few minutes to upvote answer.

Comment: When I upvote, the system tells me "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. "  So I will upvote your answer when I have 15 reputations.